# Angular App freezing in both Edge and Firefox

Tags: angular, firefox, rxjs, microsoft-edge, zone.js

I have recently been working on an angular application. It works well in all browsers I can find on both mobile and pc, except Edge and Firefox. Both Edge and Firefox are freezing without any output to the console. Firefox tells me after a while that the page has frozen and gives me an option to terminate the script. The following is then printed to the console:

```
Error: Script terminated by timeout at:
__spread@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:86417:14
debugCheckNoChangesNode@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:49939:38
debugCheckRenderNodeFn@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:49893:13
View_HeaderComponent_7/<@ng:///AppModule/HeaderComponent.ngfactory.js:187:5
debugUpdateRenderer@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:49882:12
checkNoChangesView@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:49237:5
callViewAction@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:49474:21
execEmbeddedViewsAction@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:49457:17
checkNoChangesView@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:49236:5
callViewAction@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:49474:21
execComponentViewsAction@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:49436:13
checkNoChangesView@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:49238:5
callViewAction@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:49474:21
execComponentViewsAction@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:49436:13
checkNoChangesView@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:49238:5
callWithDebugContext@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:50146:22
debugCheckNoChangesView@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:49827:12
./node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js/ViewRef_.prototype.checkNoChanges@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:47648:55
./node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js/ApplicationRef.prototype.tick/<@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:43378:62
./node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js/ApplicationRef.prototype.tick@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:43378:17
next/<@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:43268:99
./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js/</ZoneDelegate.prototype.invoke@http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:7433:17
onInvoke@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:42619:24
./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js/</ZoneDelegate.prototype.invoke@http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:7432:17
./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js/</Zone.prototype.run@http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:7183:24
./node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js/NgZone.prototype.run@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:42533:16
next@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:43268:69
./node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js/EventEmitter.prototype.subscribe/schedulerFn<@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:42350:36
./node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js/SafeSubscriber.prototype.__tryOrUnsub@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:69383:13
./node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js/SafeSubscriber.prototype.next@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:69321:17
./node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js/Subscriber.prototype._next@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:69254:9
./node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js/Subscriber.prototype.next@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:69229:13
./node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subject.js/Subject.prototype.next@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:68994:17
./node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js/EventEmitter.prototype.emit@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:42334:54
checkStable@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:42588:13
onLeave@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:42655:5
onInvoke@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:42622:17
./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js/</ZoneDelegate.prototype.invoke@http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:7432:17
./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js/</Zone.prototype.runGuarded@http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:7196:28
./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js/</Zone.prototype.wrap/<@http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:7174:24
```

I have all the polyfills included.

The point is that it is working in all browsers including IE and not Firefox & Edge. That makes me wonder what is wrong. The app is pretty large, so including it or stripping it down is not an option.

Any ideas?

Comment: What is happening in your HeaderComponent?

Comment: I am using *ngIf to check if the data to show is loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of debugging I finally fount why it was freezing. I was using the MutationObserver api which turned out to be the cause of the freezing.